# Overwriting CSS Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to surcharge Bootstrap CSS and for that i have created a new overwrite.css file.

In my different test I need to display a black background (It's only for test) but nothing.

```
<div id="myBackground"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#myBackground  { background-color: black; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

Comment: load the bootstrap CSS before your overwrite.css. Provide more code

Comment: Add the `overwrite.css` after boostrap's css style tag

Comment: That's a symfony3 project :<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/bootstrap.min.css") }}">                             
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/overwrite.css" ) }}">

Comment: It works fine: http://www.bootply.com/Djw6rZKdXi We can't help if we can't recreate the issue. Check for console errors and make sure the CSS files are loading properly.

Comment: Yes it should work! But for some reason, it doesn't. It's what i did..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

overwrite.css : "It means what it means"! You can't create your own id or class if bootstrap doesn't know what is this...

So, you must create a third css file (style.css for example) and load this after bootstrap.css and overwrite.css !

After this, all is working!

Thanks

Comment: I can't because it was a comment. ... -1 -1 -1 -1 !

Answer (score 0):

so i don't know where exactly you need change the bg color use these after bootstrap or  in `<style></style>` inside `<head></head>`
if you want change the page background

```
body {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

if as container or column

```
col-md-5 {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are selecting your element with more specificity than the bootstrap css.

1. Load your overwrite.css file after bootstrap.
2. Try selecting a parent element before your `#myBackground` div. For example,

`.main-content #myBackground {}`

3. Find the attributes bootstrap is using that you want to override... for example if in bootstrap.css there is `.navbar-nav {background:#000;}` then you need to make sure your overwrite has a `background` attribute declared, such as `#myNavbar {background:#555;}`